# Newbie chrome-plugin developer needs help getting started with NPAPI

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, google-chrome-extension, compiler-errors, npapi

Although only having done a very little in C++ before I'm trying to compile the following chrome plugin so that I can see how it works and use that as a starting point to develop something similar: http://code.google.com/p/minimizetotray/source/browse/trunk/?r=17#trunk%2FDLL

So far I have taken the following steps: downloaded the source, opened it in MS Visual Studio Pro 2008, and obtained a few of SDKs and headerfiles it was asking for including the latest version of the NPAPI headers: http://npapi-sdk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/headers/

Now I get the following errors when I try to compile and have no idea how to sort this.

```
    Compiling...
JSMethods.cpp
c:\documents and settings\dell customer\desktop\dll\jsmethods.cpp(92) : error C2039: 'UTF8length' : is not a member of '_NPString'
        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\plugin\npruntime.h(85) : see declaration of '_NPString'
c:\documents and settings\dell customer\desktop\dll\jsmethods.cpp(101) : error C2039: 'UTF8characters' : is not a member of '_NPString'
        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\plugin\npruntime.h(85) : see declaration of '_NPString'
```

Etc...

Apart from those two errors it all seems dandy, its not asking for missing includes or anything. Any help appreciated!

Comment: What version of the XulRunner SDK are you using?

Comment: you may also want to look at http://firebreath.org instead of doing it by hand -- much easier, particularly for a newbie (but many advanced plugin developers use it as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken on the latest SDK the _NPString struct is defined as...

```
typedef char NPUTF8;
typedef struct _NPString {
    const NPUTF8 *UTF8Characters;
    uint32_t UTF8Length;
} NPString;
```

And in your code you are calling UTF8length instead of UTF8Length (uppercase L).

Comment: It compiles, wahooooooooo! Guess I could have worked that one out myself if I'd really tried, good job I'm posting anonymously  :-P Don't know why the DLL I made is three times the size of the distributed one but it does seem to work, thanks loads for your help!

Comment: Probably you have in the setting "Use MFC in a Static Library"... a good place to start with NPAPI is http://colonelpanic.net/2009/03/building-a-firefox-plugin-part-one/

Comment: Which means that the code also needs to change to use UTF8Characters instead of UTF8characters:

std::string ret = NPVARIANT_TO_STRING(locationValue).UTF8Characters;